# Changing dropdown selected text with jQuery

Tags: jquery

So, i have a dropdown (on Bigcommerce site) with preselected value of "Please Choose an Option" that is used for size selection:

```
<select name="attribute[95]">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Please Choose an Option</option>

                    <option value="73">Small</option>
                    <option value="74">Medium</option>
                    <option value="75">Large</option>
            </select>
```

I am trying to change it with jQuery so instead of "Please Choose an Option" it says "Choose an option".
So far i have this snippet:

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('select option:contains(\'-- Please Choose an Option --\')').text("Choose an Option")
            })
            </script>
```

Which does the trick but only after the user clicks on the dropdown, aka, when the page loads, old text appears and new one is shown only if the person clicks on the dropdown...

Any suggestions on what is wrong?

Comment: I don't think that is how you want to approach changing the text.  Why not just change the text in the HTML?

Comment: Cant, that is a Bigcommerce Global variable and i dont have access to it, i can only do it like this (which Bigcommerce recommends as well)

Comment: Are you using a plugin for your `<select>` elements?

Comment: I am not, but there is a lot of stuff that get pushed from BigCommerce end.
Weird part is that this snippet works, but only AFTER the user clicks on dropdown (then it shows properly)

Comment: It looks like the selector is wrong, and it should be   `$('select option:contains(\'Please Choose an Option\')')`. http://jsfiddle.net/onme3yu6/ . That doesn't explain why it works after you click around a bit though...

Comment: @Thisandthat Which file are you inserting your JS in to? It sounds like it's only being executed when the dropdown is clicked.

Comment: tried everything, header, footer, straight into product page template... and puff, nothing

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the below,

Select the first option using `first-child`

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $('select option:first-child').text("Choose an Option");   
});
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('select option').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == 'Please Choose an Option') {
            $(this).text('Choose an Option');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. JSFiddle of your code: [http://jsfiddle.net/545fhgwc/](http://jsfiddle.net/545fhgwc/)

Comment: What if BigCommerce decide to load 'Please choose an option' last? http://jsfiddle.net/545fhgwc/2/

Comment: @DaveSalomon in a way i agree with u but in a way i'm not..There is something called usability. Considering about usability aspect **please choose an option** won't be the last..My answer is for the question..

Comment: Ufff, same thing happens. Text gets changed but only after i click on the dropdown, on the page load it stays the same as before. So weird :(
I would share an URL but the site isnt online

Comment: @jlocker A lot of clothing sites don't have "select a size" as an option in the list, but it is the default value when the page loads. If BigCommerce follow suite, your solution will cause problems. By matching on the text, at least nothing 'bad' happens. It's perfectly realistic that the first option isn't neccessarily 'please choose an option'.